# Inherited non-enumerable properties in for...in loop (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have an object *p*, with an enumerable propery *x*.

```
var p = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
  x: {
    value: "frog",
    enumerable: true
  }
});
```

I create an object, that inherits from *p*, and overrides property *x*, with a non-enumerable property

```
var o = Object.create(p, {
  x: {
    value: "bird",
    enumerable: false
  }
});
```

What do you think, will the property *x* be enumerated in a for...in loop of *o*?

```
for (var n in o) {
  console.log(n);
}
```

Well, in Chrome and IE9 it will be enumerated (which is, I think, quite wierd); in FF, it won't be enumerated.

Which one is the right behaviour?

Here is a complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/hnvsM/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in V8. There's been a bug report on this for quite a while.

[Issue 705:    Non-enumerable property fails to shadow inherited enumerable property from for-in](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=705&q=enumerable&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20HW%20OS%20Area%20Stars)

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4), it's definitely a bug in chrome and ie9. Emphasis mine.

> Enumerating the properties of an object includes enumerating
>   properties of its prototype, and the prototype of the prototype, and
>   so on, recursively; **but a property of a prototype is not enumerated if
>   it is “shadowed”** because some previous object in the prototype chain
>   has a property with the same name. **The values of [[Enumerable]]
>   attributes are not considered when determining if a property of a
>   prototype object is shadowed** by a previous object on the prototype
>   chain.