# Do I need to check hasOwnProperty when iterating through an object using for-in

Tags: javascript

We use `for in` to iterating through an object as follows

```
var object = { "a":"foo", "b":"bar"}

for (var key in object) {
   var element = object[key];
}
```

I have seen my seniors recommend me to check if the property exists before actually accessing it. Why? because if a `for in` is giving me a key it means it exists...

why should I write `for in` like below:

```
for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var element = object[key];            
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inherited non-enumerable properties in for...in loop (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714938/inherited-non-enumerable-properties-in-for-in-loop-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want only the properties of that object, you need to use `hasOwnProperty` function. Without that check you will also get the properties which are got from the prototype of that object.

See the example

```js
var object = { "a":"foo", "b":"bar"};

for (var key in object) {
   console.log(key);
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(object,{ "c" : "gar"});

console.log('After setting prototype');

for (var key in object) {
   console.log(key);
}

console.log('Using hasOwnProperty');

for (var key in object) {
   if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      console.log(key);
   }
}
```

Look, after checking with `hasOwnProperty`, we pass that `key` which is from the prototype (`c`).